# Raycaster does not find intersect even though it should

Tags: three.js

I am using a raycaster for a projection of a point onto a face. But somehow that doesn't seem to work. I.e. taking point (25,25,300) and direction (0,0,-1) the raycaster doesn't find and intersect with a box of size (30,30,30) located at (0,0,0).  Am I doing sth wrong?

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 30);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var dir = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
var p = new THREE.Vector3(25,25,300);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(p, dir);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(mesh); // returns an empty array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your example, first is that you are using the method `raycaster.intersectObjects` which takes an array as argument, when you should be using `raycaster.intersectObject` which takes an object.

Secondly, you are missing the mesh.

Try these values: `var p = new THREE.Vector3(15,15,300);` instead. The image below illustrates the problem..

[image]